# https 301 errors and SEO

Tags: seo, https, http-status-code-301, forwarding

This question is related to a few tools that are returning errors and that I am not sure what to do about them, if anything.

At:
http://andylangton.co.uk/online-tools/http-status-analyser

if I analyze http://drchrono.com

I get "Status code is 301. Status is Moved Permanently to https://drchrono.com/."

This makes sense but if I then analyze that address, https://drchrono.com/
I get the same error.

Do I need to fix this?

How?

Does this affect SEO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just an error in the tool you are using, if you test this http://www.seoconsultants.com/tools/headers.asp you get correct OK 200 answer

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge it will not effect your SEO. if it will be show 302 error that may be concern in terms of SEO

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).